# Does each browser render css differently?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I designed a page and was testing in chrome. After completing it, when I checked in firefox, I noticed few inconsistencies. For example, one thing that surprised me was the popup I made. I was doing like :

```
$('#login-pop-up').css('top','3200px');
```

It showed fine in *chrome*, but in *firefox* it showed way below. I do not know what does that mean ? When I set a property of top to 3200px, why it doesn't remain the same in firefox when the testing-machine is same.

Does each browser render css differently ? `top` for firefox won't be same as chrome or opera?

Comment: Every implementation is different. Every browser has bugs.

Comment: What do you mean by "but in firefox it showed way below"? A 3200px top value would seem to be pretty far down for any browser.

Comment: @Alohci Interesting !

Comment: @j08691 I was working on a parallax theme.

Comment: Do you just want to know if the browsers render css differently ? If yes, then yes... It depends on the engine used... In that case FF use gecko while chrome now use blink. If you want to get help fixing those differences, you should provide a demo

Comment: Simple answer is yes they do - they all try to work to w3c standards (apart from ie which seems to work to it's own) and most modern browsers are now quite standardised but they still do have their own little quirks.

Comment: Have you tried [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) ?

Comment: On a side note: I can only recommend to cross-browser test frequently during development; if you finish your project in e.g. Chrome - as you did it - it will look slightly different in IE/Firefox/Safari/Opera/etc., but the same would happen if you only test in Firefox or only in IE and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relative elements on your document. CSS is a stylesheet and almost all browsers target basic CSS properties same way. For eg: position:absolute with top and left margin specified (with width of the element and height also specified) should return same results on different browsers.

---

There are some CSS properties which are inbuilt, that the color of the font should be black, there should be a 1px border on input boxes, bla bla..

Source: ME